# Custom grey scale image with numpy, openCV and python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I want to average a slice of a numpy array (its an image).

Currently i'm iterating over each pixel as follows but its dreadfully slow. I know there is a better way but I cant work it out. Its probably the numpy fancy indexing but i'm stuck.

I've used openCV to read the image into a numpy array with the shape 640,480,3 and I want to change the each of the last bit i.e [123,121,234] to the average of that slice for each of the 640x480.

You don't have to give me the answer but a shove in the right direction would be helpful.

This is whats slow for me:

```
 def bw_image_arr(self):

    for x in self.images:
        for y in x:
            for z in y:
                z = z.mean()
```

Comment: Use axis argument for `.mean`.

Comment: Do you want calculate mean value of each RGB channel?

Comment: I am experimenting and I want to change all 3 values to the mean. I need to leave the 3 channels there. Its actually in this format as its an array of images. 50,640,480,3

Comment: What would be the shape of the final output?

Comment: 50,640,480,3 the same as before but the ,3 which was originally [251,145,125] would become [174,174,174]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`axis` argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to do mean-reduction along last axis and then broadcast to the original shape with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) -

```
np.broadcast_to(images.mean(axis=-1,keepdims=True),images.shape)
```

That `np.broadcast_to` helps us on achieving memory efficiency by giving us original shaped view into the averaged array. If you need the final output with its own memory space, append with `.copy()` -

```
np.broadcast_to(images.mean(axis=-1,keepdims=True),images.shape).copy()
```

Alternatively, we can use `np.repeat` -

```
images.mean(axis=-1,keepdims=True).repeat(images.shape[-1],axis=-1)
```

The posted solutions work for ndarrays of generic dimensions. Hence, will work on one image or a set of images with the desired result of average along the last axis being broadcasted/replicated/repeated along the same.

Also, note that the final output would be of `float` dtype. So, we might want to convert or/and round to int for usual image-dtype of unsigned-int dtype output.

Comment: This is exactly the result I wanted. Thank you very much for your answer. I think I need to do some reading up on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to average over the x and y axes. In your case the axes 1 and  2 (you can input it in numpy.mean as a tuple). Then if you have 50 images in the first dimension example you will get (50, 3) shaped array.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I'm struggling to understand but with enough tinkering I will get there. I find working it out my self helps me grasp the concept better.